# for loop output not saving

Tags: powershell, for-loop, replace

I have fundamental gap with how for loops work, I am new to scripting. 
Can someone explain to me how I would save my total `$i` output in a variable? In the second example I tried this a couple different ways and `$c` never has a value.

The script is just supposed to be a function that parses a list of IP address by getting rid of extra spaces with sort, and replace to remove the IPV6 addresses / clean up the output. 
I just need to be able to save the output so I can continue working on the next part of this.

Working part of my script:

```
Function Get-LsweeperIPStrip {
    param([string]$path)
    $attempt = @(get-content -Path $path | Where-Object {$_ -NotLike '*fe80*' })
    $b = ($attempt.replace(";", "`n")) | Sort-Object 

    foreach ($i in $b) {
        $i.replace("`"", "")

    }

}
```

I thought this would work:

```
Function Get-LansweeperIPStrip {
    param([string]$path)
    $attempt = @(get-content -Path $path | Where-Object {$_ -NotLike '*fe80*' })
    $b = ($attempt.replace(";", "`n")) | Sort-Object 
    $c = @()   
    foreach ($i in $b) {
        $c += $i.replace("`"", "")

    }
}
```

Here is some example addresses from `Get-Content`:

```
"172.21.69.139;10.162.0.146;fe80::68a2:de4c:b4b6:5518
10.140.94.163;fe80::248e:4a6e:8f94:c1e5
10.133.124.13"
10.25.159.103
10.25.159.105;fe80::1838:fcc8:3d7d:362f
10.25.159.106
10.15.160.134
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This seemed to work:


clear-host
Function Get-LansweeperIPStrip{
param([string]$path)
$attempt = @(get-content -Path $path | Where-Object {$_ -NotLike '*fe80*' })
$b = ($attempt.replace(";","`n")) | Sort-Object  
$c=
    foreach ($i in $b) {

            $i.replace("`"","") 
         }

  $c | out-file C:\Users\drewt\Desktop\dump.txt

 }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.